# What is the difference between {{view}} and {{#view}}

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to get [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MBmUs/63/) working with the latest ember version, but I get several errors. I am unable to correct the code because I lack some basic understanding. The example uses the `view` helper in two different ways:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.View contentBinding="App.myModel"}}
            {{#view App.PreviewUploadImage name="logo_image" contentBinding="content"}}
                {{view fileField}}
                {{view previewImageView width="200" height="100" srcBinding="content.myModel_src"}}
            {{/view}}
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

What is the difference between both uses (`view` and `#view`) of the view helper?
And, as a more fundamental question, what is the difference between a helper with and without the `#` prefix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that `{{view}}` is used when you don't wrap anything inside the view helper and `{{#view}}` when you have something to wrap, like in your example, also when using `{{#view}}` a closing tag `{{/view}}` has to follow. The latter is true for all block helper.

Most common example of a block helper is:

```
{{#link-to}}My link{{/link-to}}
```

And the most common non-block helper:

```
{{input type="text" value="foo"}}
```

Hope it helps.